# Mithriljs: prevent full application reload on submit

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have a single component which is just a login form.
When login is unsuccessful I get a full application reload for some reason.

This is the application main entry. All it does is the initial authentication ping. If session is up it loads the actual application, otherwise it mounts Authentication component which is just a login form.

```
var Application = {
  run() {
    m.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: cfg.apiurl("/session/ping"),
      extract(xhr) {
        return xhr.status > 200 ? xhr.status : xhr.responseText;
      }
    }).then(r => {
      var init = {
        uname: r.data.uname
      };
      router(init);
    }, e => {
      if (e === 401) {
        m.mount(document.body, Authenticate);
      }
    });
  }
};

Application.run();
```

Below is the Authentication component minus the view. It binds login variables to the view and defines submit action. When I run submit action with incorrect credentials it reloads the application.

Why does it reload the application??
Chrome console says: `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?` right after "Login Failure !!!" console message. This causes full application reload. So any on-screen error messages and popups about incorrect login simply disappear. It does print the last error message to the console "Login Failure !!!". After that, when submit function exits, it navigates to the root of the URL causing a full reload.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var Authenticate = {
  controller, view
};

function controller() {
  this.info = m.prop("");
  this.data = {
    uname: m.prop(""),
    passw: m.prop(""),
    local: m.prop(false)
  };
  this.submit = () => {
    Login.auth(this.data).then(r => {
      if (this.data.uname() === r.data.uname) {
        var init = {
          uname: r.data.uname
        };
        router(init);
      } else {
        console.log("Login Mismatch !!!");
      }
    }, e => {
      if (e === 401) {
        console.log("Login Failure !!!");
        popa();
      } else {
        console.log(`Server Errror ${e} !!!`);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the `popa()` function you execute immediately after logging `Login Failure !!!`? There isn't any code on display here that would cause the page to reload AFAICT.

Comment: This is just an error message slide in. Could be replaced with console.log(). Does not make any difference...

Comment: Well like I said, none of the Mithril code here would cause a page reload - page reload is not something Mithril would ever try to do. Going by intuition the problem is either in `popa()` or some other part of your app. If you're using a modern browser with a debugger, you should be able to set a breakpoint at `popa()` and step through it to see where the problem is. As it is, there isn't enough here to help - sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's what I thought by looking at it like hundred times, there is nothing there to cause a reload.... Removing popa() does not help. It is somewhere else. I will look at it fresh in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use HTML `form`-element, submit always triggers a page reload. You have to `preventDefault` here

```
m('form', {
  onsubmit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }, 'form content'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the late acknowledgement . I found it too. I usually use class `.form` instead of a normal form element. So I simply missed the dot and it was reloading ... Interestingly though, I was not submitting the form as such and it was still reloading on a non-submit event.